# MVC C# Accessing URL Parameters from controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, methods, parameters

I'm working on an Asp.net MVC project, using C#, and it's my first MVC project so I'm still missing basic details.

When using hyperlink on one of my pages, like this:

```
<a href="\ScheduleDetails\Index\@item.workScheduleId">
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.scheduleName)
        </a>
```

Then, the index method inside the controller of ScheduleDetails will be:

```
public ActionResult Index(long id)
{
    var scheduledetails = db.scheduleDetails.Where(s =>s.workScheduleId==id);
    this.workScheduleId = id;
    return View(scheduledetails.ToList());
}
```

Note that I already defined the variable workScheduleId as an instance private variable in the controller:

```
    private ScheduleDetailsDbContext db = new ScheduleDetailsDbContext();
    private long workScheduleId;
```

now when debugging, the index method reads the parameter correctly, and assign it to the private variable workScheduleId correctly. but when I'm trying to access workScheduleId from The Create method inside the same controller it returns 0! Although I'm sure that the variable get assigned to the correct value at index method, why does this value lost when calling the Create method? How can I access the parameters from Create method or any other method?

Comment: What `Create` method!! And each request initializes a new instance of your controller so the value of `workScheduleId` is lost the moment you exit the `Index` method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why custom type variable is not saving value MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903335/why-custom-type-variable-is-not-saving-value-mvc)

Comment: Basically, you need to use something like `TempData` to persist values through requests. In the link I provided above, you can understand one way to do that.

Comment: If you're trying to persist values across requests you will need to do that with session variables - `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionString"] = sessionValue; `